# Protecting HMVC modules from users not logged in

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, authentication, hmvc

I'm developing a website using HMVC patterns and CodeIgniter.

I have some modules which should never be accessable if a user is not logged in.

When a user logs in, it sets a session `is_logged_in`

Now, I tried this code and it *seems* to work as it should, however I am not sure if it's secure.

I put this in the *controllers constructor*:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == NULL) { exit; }
```

Is this secure, or can it be bypassed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// make helper helper, ex. my_login_helper

```
if (!function_exists('is_logged_in')){

    function is_logged_in(){
        // Get current CI instance
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // use $CI->session instead of $this->session
        $user = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if (!isset($user)) { return false; } else { return true; }
    } 

  }
```

//  repeating the same code on every controller just to check if the user is logged in 
//  make My_Controller

```
  function _remap($method)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $method) && $this->my_login_helper->is_logged_in())
        { $this->$method(); }
        else {  redirect('/auth/'); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create core subclass controller like `MY_Controller` that has a constructor that calls your security, then by extending it on the controllers you would like to protect.it will be Much better than putting  it all over the controllers one by one, thus code re usability. As for the question on security, that would suffice adding some unique session that only your system can read.